# Whats the difference when instantiating these arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why is this not allowed ? Gets the error " Cannot convert from StaticPhysicsObject* to StaticPhysicsObject"

```
StaticPhysicsObject* shape = static_cast<StaticPhysicsObject*>(malloc(sizeof(StaticPhysicsObject*)* shapes.size()));
shape[0] = new StaticPhysicsObject();
```

But this works.

```
StaticPhysicsObject* shape[100];
shape[0] = new StaticPhysicsObject();
```

I know this is a pointer to  an array full of pointers. I just don't understand why that the first sample does not give the same results as this sample.

```
StaticPhysicsObject** shape = static_cast<StaticPhysicsObject**>(malloc(sizeof(StaticPhysicsObject*)* shapes.size()));
shape[0] = new StaticPhysicsObject();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `StaticPhysicsObject* shape = new StaticPhysicsObject();`, you define a pointer to a `StaticPhysicsObject` object. Accessing this pointer via `shape[0]` is equivalent to `*(shape + 0)`, which is the same as `*shape` The type of this expression is `StaticPhysicsObject`, i.e not a pointer.

`new StaticPhysicsObject();` however yields a `StaticPhysicsObject*` pointer. You cannot assign a pointer to the object to a plain object though.

Answer (score 2):

```
StaticPhysicsObject* shape = 
  static_cast<StaticPhysicsObject*>(malloc(sizeof(StaticPhysicsObject*)* shapes.size()));
```

That allocates an array of `StaticPhysicsObject`s of size `shapes.size()`.

```
shape[0] = new StaticPhysicsObject();
```

`new StaticPhysicsObject()` returns a pointer to a `StaticPhysicsObject`, *not* a `StaticPhysicsObject`. `shape` holds `StaticPhysicsObject`s, not pointers.

Note that using `malloc` and `static_cast`ing it to get a pointer to a dynamic array in C++ is **evil**. `malloc` knows nothing of constructors, so you'll just get some uninitialized memory for objects of class type. C++ has `new[]`, but you'd be even better off just using a `std::vector`.

Comment: I have been using placement new "new (memoryAddress) type()". Why would a vector be better ?

Comment: @Student123 why are you using placement `new`? Are you writing optimized containers or memory allocators? `std::vector` is far more flexible than dynamically allocated arrays and let you avoid the pitfall of c-style arrays.

Comment: i use placement new to construct the objects in the memory that i want it. And i'm just storing my game entity's in arrays like this with an int specifying the active number.

Comment: If you have a dynamically-allocated varying size collection, you should absolutely use `std::vector`, it was purpose-built to solve that issue.

Comment: Using a vector won't help solve the problems I had to solve, so I didn't.